# D3 svg element duplicated in Safari webarchive

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, webarchive

For particular reasons the project I'm working on needs to use the webarchive feature of Safari.  I'm using a simplified version of [this pen](http://codepen.io/228miles/pen/BNoZdv) for a progress bar. The simpler code can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjZqdj) and below.

If this page is saved as a webarchive, the progress bar is duplicated below itself.  If it is animated, the 'ghost' below it is inactive.  I was wondering if there was a workaround to this, so that there was no duplicate.  Any attempt at changing visibility settings, such as hiding or display:none failed.

Edit: I have circumvented the issue for now by using a bootstrap progress bar instead.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


 <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
#play-progress {
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:20px;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 36px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#play-svg {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#progress-bar {
  fill:blue;
}
</style>
  </head>

  <body role="document">

  <div id= "play-progress"> </div> 

<script>

//Progress bar
var data_index = 0;
var progress_width = 400;
var speed = 650;
var animation;

// add the progress bar svg
var progress = d3.select("#play-progress").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("id","play-svg")
  .attr("width", progress_width)
  .attr("height", 36);
// append a rect, which will move to the right as the animation plays
// this creates the progress bar effect
progress.append("rect")
  .attr("id","progress-bar")
  .attr("width", progress_width)
  .attr("height", 36)
  .attr("x",0)
  .attr("y",0);

function setProgressWidth(num) {
    progress_width = 400;
    document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = num;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```